# Stacking images with CSS Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am learning to use `CSS` flexbox and I would like to render a big image on the left and two small images stacked on top of each other. How can I do this using `CSS` flexbox?

[image]

```html
<div class="container">
      <img class="image1" src="#" alt="null">
      <img class="image1" src="#" alt="null">
      <img class="image3" src="#" alt="null">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this like this:

```css
.container {
     display: flex;
}
.side {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
}
.image {
     display: block;
     margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="null">
      <div class="side">
          <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/120x90" alt="null">
          <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/120x150" alt="null">
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good, Can we make it responsive?

Comment: Vishal, that's exactly what I am trying to figure it now!

Comment: @Leyth [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exotkfcr/1/) Start with this. It's a little bit tricky. If I were you and wanted it to be responsive I would use flex only for the sidebar.

Comment: @Green flexbox is just way too confusing. Would these be easier if I tried `position` instead?

Comment: @Leyth It really depends on what you really want to achieve. Is it _one-big-image-with-fixed-width-sidebar_ or _one-big-image-with-fluid-width-sidebar-and-other-nice-stuff-on-it_ or _fixed-height-is-most-important_ or _one-big-image-something-else_. ;)

Comment: it is one-big-image-with-fixed-width-sidebar

Comment: @Leyth Then [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6e3fzqt/3/) should be more useful for you. (: