# Encountering an obstacle in flexbox, positioning one div under another while keeping a third to the side

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

Here is the CSS, from the media query, all display:flex

```css
video {
  height: 800px;
  width: auto;
}

.info {
  order: 2;
  border: 0.5 px solid #f7f7f7;
  background: white;
  width: 566.03px;
  height: max-content;
  position: relative;
}

.video-div {
  border: 0.5 px solid #f7f7f7;
  background: white;
  width: 566.03px;
  order: 1;
}

.interaction {
  order: 3;
  border: 0.5 px solid #f7f7f7;
  background: white;
  width: 566.03px;
  height: max-content;
}

.middle {
  height: 569px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div> First div</div>
  <div> Second div</div>
  <div> Third div</div>
</main>
```

[This is where I am.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAQO4.jpg) I need to move the highlighted div, under the second div,(The small one "therock" div).

Comment: The code doesn't really replicate your image very well (do you have the entire HTML with classes?), but you're looking to essentially stack the items within flex-box. Flex-box on its own doesn't do a great job at accomplishing what you're looking for in my opinion, as CSS grid is awesome for this. Here's a method that might work but nesting the content within the second div ("therock") - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319784/stacking-images-with-css-flexbox

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with flex pretty easily.
In my example below, there is a main div with `flex-direction` set to row.  The right column is set to `display: flex` with `flex-direction` column. This stacks the children of main horizontally and children of right vertically.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%
}
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  background: lightblue;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: pink;
}

.fill {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div>Blah blah blah</div>
    <div class="fill">More blah blah</div>
  </div>
</div>
```